# Deleting Git Bash Memory

Tags: git, git-bash, reset

In some applications, you can reconfigure it by erasing all information from the memory occupied by the application and resetting it from scratch as if it had never been used before. Is it possible to reset the Windows Git Bash terminal by resetting it and starting over?

---

Rationale: I have the following problem:

[image]

I can't clone my repository to the folder I'm accessing, remembering that my initial error was in the command statement to configure the server proxy, forgetting to look up references to resolve the error I was causing earlier:

[image]

That's why I'm confused and not knowing what to do! Because I could not locate the server proxy and by placing the command to solve the problem he accepted normally, BUT because of him I am unable to clone my Git Hub repository. What can I do to reset these proxy settings and start all over again?

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to do but restarting Git Bash will not remove your repositories.

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to do either but possibly the 'clear' command?

Comment: This is where I got @ArkadiuszDrabczyk! I tried to uninstall it and installed it again and realized that the data remained in the application memory. My goal was to figure out how to clear the memory cache that stores all Git Bash information.

Comment: I didn't write Git Bash and still don't know what you want to do but I'm inclined to believe there is no cache at all. Describe what you want to do in more details.

Comment: The "clear" command clears only the screen I'm accessing, but the settings are retained.

Comment: I will add some more information to this post! I'll make it a little clearer. Thanks for the help. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Global settings (from running `git config --global`) are in your global Git settings file, whose location depends on your OS and Git installation.  You can:

- remove them using `git config --global --unset`, or
- change them to a new value using `git config --global` again, or
- add to them using `git config --global --add` (don't do this for `https.proxy` though!),<sup>1</sup> or
- use your preferred editor—which you can set with `git config --global`—to edit your configuration, using `git config --global --edit`.

Of course, to do the last, you'd need to configure your preferred editor first, so as to be able to run your preferred editor to edit your configuration to set your preferred editor. :-) It's also important that this editor be "well behaved" in terms of the way Git likes to run commands: `vim`, `emacs`, and other command-line-directed editors tend to work well, while GUI-based editors like those built in to Xcode or Eclipse or Android Studio or whatever tend not to work so well here.

(There are more things you can do with `git config`.  The above list is just the most frequently useful set of things.)

Note further that most of the settings in your *global* configuration can be overridden by a setting in a *local* configuration.  Each Git repository has its own local configuration file.  Using `git config` without `--global` (or with `--local` if you want to be super-explicit) makes Git use the local configuration file, so that, e.g., `git config --edit` invokes your preferred editor on this local configuration file.

If all else fails, you *can* remove the global configuration file entirely,<sup>2</sup> but you should never *have* to do that.  You should not remove the local config file.  Git keeps track of some information about the repository itself, and the way your system behaves, in there under the various `core` settings.

---

<sup>1</sup>There are not many settings that make sense with `git config --add`.  Unless you are using one of these, you should probably *not* use the `--add` flag, if for no other reason than it makes it harder to clean them up later.  (You should already know if some setting is additive when you read the documentation describing that setting, which should say so.  For instance, `remote.origin.fetch` is an additive setting.)

In general the way these configuration entries work is that Git reads each config file in sequence: system first, then global, then local.  A setting in the system config sets some internal variable.  Then, any *different* setting in the global config overwrites the variable with a new value, and any *different* setting in the local config overwrites again.

If you use `git config --add`, each setting overwrites as Git processes the file, so that the *last* setting in the file is the one remaining.  Then Git moves on to the next, more-local config file, whose *last* setting overrides, and so on.  So that's how local overrides global which overrides system, but also why only the *last* setting matters, for most configurations—and that's why using `--add` is pointless and just makes a mess if you have to clean up all the extra settings.

For special configuration variables, though, they just keep accumulating.  The way this works is that Git invokes (or has built into it) the equivalent of `git config --get-all`, which prints one line *per* setting, rather than waiting until it's read the last line of the last config file.  Then whatever it is that uses these cumulative variables uses each of those settings that got printed out.

<sup>2</sup>To remove it, use your OS-provided file-removal tool, e.g., `rm` on Linux, on the name of the global configuration file—which in turn depends on your OS and Git installation.  For a typical Linux setup it would be in `$HOME/.gitconfig` or `$HOME/.config/git/config` or `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/git/config`, again depending on installation and, in this case, whether some of these variables are set and paths exist.

Answer (score 0):

this error I didn't specify in the question was as follows:

`Failed to connect to github.com port 443: Timed out.`

This error appeared after I cloned the Git Hub server repository to a folder stored on my computer. I came to see a solution published right here in Stack Overflow and saw the following line that I hoped was my miracle:

`git config --global http.proxy http[s]://userName(encoded):password()encoded @proxyaddress:port`

Only when running this command, the author did not specify well the parameters that would be used for this configuration and even then I felt cheerful and pressed in enter to see what would give. Look at what you've done:

[image]

When trying to perform cloning my repository it returns to me that the parameters I put in the line above were incorrect, then I did the following:

[image]

Now, when trying to clone the folder, a window was opened to select the type of user I was and pressed on `<manager>` and clicked OK. From there, cloning was done normally. If you want to comment on this solution below, I appreciate it. ;-)